# No boot signature

Tags: usb

I used WINusb on Ubuntu to make a bootable Win10 medium on a USB, but when I tried booting the booted medium I got this error:

[image]

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which winusb did you use? The one from webupd8 or the one directly from the terminal?

Comment: I installed my version directly from the terminal.

Comment: yeah that one has some issues, might not be related to this. Can't find the stupid link, but the problem you're facing is that the first sectors of your usb has been "corrupt". There are some things you could do if you boot back into Ubuntu and install ghex, otherwise I would recommend you to use a different usb creator.

Comment: Would you like to give me an example? +1

Comment: we are talking about you writing your own boot signature for the usb using ghex. Which kinda falls down to looking something like this http://i1-linux.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/GHex_1.jpg

Comment: I have never done anything like that before. How easy is it?

Comment: in my experience at least its a lot harder, than just creating a new bootable usb with another program. Like unetbootin or really any other usb creator programs out there